# What is the domain of the inverse function

Tags: calculus, integration

$f(x)=(x + 6)/(4x + 3)$

(a) Find the inverse function of $f$.

My solution to (a) is

$x=(y+6)/(4y+3)$

$(y+6)/(4y+3)=x$

$y+6=4xy+3x$

$y+6-4xy=3x$

$-4xy+y+6=3x$

$y=-(3(x-2))/(4x-1)$

I replaced the $y$ with $f^{-1}$, thus, $f^{-1} (x)=-(3(x-2))/(4x-1)$.

(b) What is the domain of $f$ ? What is the domain of the inverse function?

I think the domain for f is  $\mathbb R\setminus\{-\frac34\}$ , because if we substitute with $-\frac34$ we get zero in the denominator,
and also for the inverse I assume the domain is $\mathbb R\setminus\{\frac14\}$ for the same reason.

Please help me in part (b)

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: set your denominator, $4x - 1 = 0$.